# Draw content under both status bar and navbar while maintaining fitsSystemWindows="true" behaviour

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to draw content under both status bar and navigation bar with them being completely transparent while also taking advantage of `fitsSystemWindows="true"`.

For the status bar, `fitsSystemWindows="true"` along with the following code works fine.

```
getWindow() .getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

[image]

However, when I add the following line to draw content under the navigation bar, the insets that we get from `fitsSystemWindows="true"` are no longer available.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

[image]

Some solutions include obtaining the statusbar and navigation bar heights like so

```
getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android"));
```

and using it as padding.

However, this method is discouraged.

Is there any way to maintain the behaviour of fitsSystemWindows="true" while drawing content under both the status bar and the navigation bar? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you just draw an illustration so that it can be clear

Comment: @SaiJayant I have included screenshots. As you can see, in the first screenshot, the AppBar and the rest of the content is properly laid out with the appropriate insets provided by fitsSystemWindows="true". In the second secreenshot, the insets disappear. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the flag

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow();
            w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            w.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
           w.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

        }
```

Then push your view using these two methods

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static boolean hasImmersive(Context ctx) {

    if (!cached) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            hasImmersive = false;
            cached = true;
            return false;
        }
        Display d = ((WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        DisplayMetrics realDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        d.getRealMetrics(realDisplayMetrics);

        int realHeight = realDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int realWidth = realDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        d.getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        int displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        hasImmersive = (realWidth > displayWidth) || (realHeight > displayHeight);
        cached = true;
    }

    return hasImmersive;
}
```

Apply padding accordingly

```
 if (hasImmersive(this)) {
            yourView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, getSoftButtonsBarHeight());

        }
```

And get the height of System soft button

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private int getSoftButtonsBarHeight() {
        // getRealMetrics is only available with API 17 and +
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int usableHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
            int realHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
            if (realHeight > usableHeight)
                return realHeight - usableHeight;
            else
                return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Screenshots 
[image: Here is the screen shot]

**EDIT:** To preserve the `fitsSystemWindows="true"` behaviour for the notification bar, add the `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` and other flags after the window insets have been applied to your `View` which has `fitsSystemWindows` set to `true`. This will ensure that the insets have been applied normally before applying the no-limit flag.

```
yourViewWithFitsSystemWindows.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
        @Override
        public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {
            if(insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop() == 0) return insets; // This is needed.
            v.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);

            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            // add other flags
            return insets;
        }
    });
```

This, along with setting the bottom padding, gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks. This works for the navigation bar. If we could also account for the notification bar inset too, then this answer would be complete. Do you have anything for that?